# AWS CORS issue: Ajax response comes as Error even after getting 200 status code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, cors

I am trying to call an API with the help of ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data, statusText, xhr) {
            console.log("Calling success");
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log(data.status);
        },
        complete: function(data, statusText, xhr) {
            console.log("Calling Complete");
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log(data.status);
        },
        error: function(data, statusText, xhr) {
            console.log("Calling error");
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log(data.status);
        }
    });
```

After calling the ajax this is the response in firefox:

[image]

You can see in the picture, I am getting `200 statuscode` and in the response, I am getting my JSON data.

Below is the snap of console, after calling ajax.

[image]

below is the error object:

```
Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }
```

Error I found after digging into the object :

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'url I passed in ajax'. at Object.send (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:14955) at Function.ajax (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:4:10579) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://mywebsitestatic.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/:258:4) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:6404) at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:3179)
```

Any Idea what is the error all about.

I have tried to refer many questions from the stackoverflow.com but No one matches with my scenario.
Can anybody please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: It looks like the API is returning an error, do you have access to the server side code?

Comment: The response tab in inspect element does not show any error, in fact, it shows the data we are getting from the response.@robertc

Comment: So what is the object in the console with the property `1: "error"`?

Comment: Is the URL you're calling the same as the one hosting the website? If not you're probably being blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: @robertc let me find the error object

Comment: @BhavikJoshi are you receivng JSON back from the server? If so, this behavior can be caused by invalid JSON data. I recommend taking the response and validating using a tool such as http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: This is the error object Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: @ alpha-before-beta  Yes I am getting the  valid json in response. 
{
 "data": {
  "uname": "bhaviksjoshi"
 }
}

Comment: Add your error object to the question, it's impossible to read in comments.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Why the `url` is passing as `'url I passed in ajax'`? Pass valid url.

Comment: @Aruna The URL is kind of private so I changed it as `url I passed in ajax`

Comment: Okay it's a CORS issue, will post an answer to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a `Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)` issue. To fix it, you had to add the below 2 response headers in the server if you can:

```
setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "origin url of your site");
setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
```

To confirm this is `CORS` issue, you can by pass this security check in `chrome` by opening this from the console as below and give a try of the url,

Windows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Mac:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

**Note**: The fix is by setting the above response headers in the server which you are trying to access from the JQuery `POST` request.

**AWS Link to enable CORS**:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

**References**: (To understand more about `CORS`)

[Cross Origin Request Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

[Cross Origin Request Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I have a doubt that the issue not only on Chrome, it does persists on all the browser. Is this the universal problem?

Comment: This is the security concern with `CORS` and all the latest browsers will block this. You should set the above two headers in the server you are calling to allow access. To confirm this is a `CORS` issue, I told you to open chrome from the console as above.

Comment: I have given you more reference URLs to understand what is `CORS` which you can refer.

Comment: What do you mean by adding it to the server? Sorry to ask you such question but I am hosting this site on AWS s3 and using AWS API gateway and AWS Lambda. Don't really know where to add it.

Comment: First you should try to understand what is `CORS` by referring the URLs I have provided. Then check `AWS` documentation about `CORS` and how to add the above headers there.

Comment: Check this URL, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html